# can't make index function work in cs50 finance

Tags: python, html, database, jinja2, cs50

I am completely stuck in making index function work in cs50 finance! This function should return in a html page a table with the details of the transactions made online (details are saved in a database). But it's not working: even if there is a transaction in my database, my function doesn't find it, the table is empty.
this is my code:

```py
def index():
    """Show portfolio of stocks"""

    rows = db.execute("SELECT symbol, price, shares FROM transactions WHERE id = :user_id", user_id=session["user_id"])

    transactions_info = []
    total_worth = 0

    for transaction_info in rows:
        symbol = rows [0]["symbol"]
        shares = rows [0]["shares"]
        price = lookup(symbol)
        worth = shares * price ["price"]
        total_worth += worth
        transactions_info.append(transaction_info)


    return render_template("index.html", rows=rows, transactions_info=transactions_info)
```

And this is my HTML page:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Index
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}

   <table class="table table-striped" style="width:100%">
    <tr>
     <th>Symbol</th>
     <th>Company</th>
     <th>Shares</th>
     <th>Price</th>
     <th>TOTAL</th>
   </tr>
 {% for transaction in transactions %}
   <tr>
     <td>{{ transaction_info.symbol }}</td>
     <td>{{ transaction_info.name }}</td>
     <td>{{ transaction_info.shares }}</td>
     <td>{{ transaction_info.price }}</td>
     <td>{{ transaction_info.worth }}</td>
   </tr>
   {% endfor %}
 </table>
  {% endblock %}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is this code a [mcve]? What have you done to try to debug this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `index()` you are sending a list called `transactions_info` here
 `return render_template("index.html", rows=rows, transactions_info=transactions_info)`

In the html you are looping over a list called `transactions` here `{% for transaction in transactions %}`.

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe I missed that :-/